# Made changes to my.cnf and mysqld wont restart - no backup

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I thought I'd be clever and update my.cnf file to add `ft_min_word_len=2` and didn't back it up first. I will never make that mistake again. Luckily, our project is still in production and no harm done.

I have no clue as to what I have done wrong in that file, as I cannot see any error logs (/var/log/mysqld.log). MySQL was running fine before I touched the config file - well, I assume it was.

By running the following command and restarting mysqld (service mysqld restart):

`mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.backup`

I got it up and running again - so that proves the config file is corrupt somehow. As soon as I put it back and restart the service it fails to start again.

This is probably not much help but this is my terminal screen showing the my.cnf file edited:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=1
atadir=/var/lib/mysql
ft_min_word_len=2
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0 

innodb_buffer_pool_size=2M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
innodb_thread_concurrency=2

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
innodb_thread_concurrency=2
```

I can't see from this is what could have gone so wrong. I have tried removing the line I added, obviously.

What are my options here? How can I restore the original config file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`atadir=/var/lib/mysql`

should be

`datadir=/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: Haha that highlights the newbie troubles I had navigating the config file using vim commands. Must have deleted a character!! Thank you very much.